# Create db_datareader and db_datawriter schemas

Tags: sql-server

I deleted the db_datareader and db_datawriter schemas in a database. Can these be added back?

I tried to add them back but I don't understand how to set up these specific ones.

Comment: Do you mean the schemas, or do you actually mean the roles?

Comment: Speculatively, I think that these schemas exist because the old way to create roles (i.e. `sp_add_role`) implicitly created schemas. `sp_add_user` does this too whereas their more modern analogs `create role` and `create user` (respectively) do not. There probably isn't any harm in having deleted them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you'd need them, but you can drop and recreate these schemas like this:

```
drop schema db_datareader
drop schema db_datawriter
go
create schema db_datareader authorization db_datareader 
go
create schema db_datawriter authorization db_datawriter
go
```

Comment: Are there no default tables needed?

Comment: These schemas are typically empty, and data from before the user/schema split in SQL 2005.  You can't drop non-empty schemas.